# Capture sentence with lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: regex

How to capture these two sentences :

```
Je ne pense pas
Je pense
```

This Re

```
Je (?=ne)|(?!ne) (pense) (?<=pas)|(?<!pas)
```

Je ahead of ne or not ahead of ne.
pas behind pense or not behind pense

Comment: could you explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, use this pattern

```
(Je(?: ne)? pense(?: pas)?)


(               # Capturing Group (1)
  Je            # match "Je"
  (?: ne)?      # match/don't capture optional "ne"
   pense        # " pense"
  (?: pas)?     # match/don't capture optional "pas"
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

the last `?` in `(?: ne)?` and `(?: pas)?` makes them optional

Comment: Correct.Explain please.

Comment: @Nicolas, explanation above

Comment: This RE ((?: ne)?pensez-vous(?: pas)?) does not capture ne in 1. ne pensez-vous pas 2. pensez-vous

Comment: This RE ((?: ne)?pensez-vous(?: pas)?) does not capture ne in 1. ne pensez-vous pas 2. pensez-vous

Comment: @Nicolas, if you want to capture change `(?: ne)?` to `( ne)?`